# Scala generic type usage in Apache Spark Dataset creation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, scala-generics

The following code creates a empty Dataset in Spark..

```
    scala> val strings = spark.emptyDataset[String]
    strings: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]
```

The signature of emptyDataset is..

```
     @Experimental  
     @InterfaceStability.Evolving
     def emptyDataset[T: Encoder]: Dataset[T] = {
         val encoder = implicitly[Encoder[T]]
         new Dataset(self, LocalRelation(encoder.schema.toAttributes), encoder)   
     }
```

Why the above signature is not forcing T to be subtype of Encoder?

It accepts T as of type String and creates a encoder for String and pass that to Dataset constructor.It finally creates Dataset[String].

Answer (score 5):

This syntax is actually a syntactic sugar for requiring an implicit `Encoder[T]`. The following functions are equivalent:

```scala
def foo[A : Encoder](a: A)

def foo[A](a: A)(implicit encoder: Encoder[A])
```

The syntax for subtyping is actually defined by type bounds, something like `A <: B` for example. I hope that helps you.